# Can't modify a function to print the content of another function

Tags: node.js, function, callback

I've written a script in `node` using three different functions supplying callback within them.

***How can I modify the `printResult()` function keeping the design as it is in order to print the content within `addGender()` function?***

This is what I have written:

```
const name = "sam"

function getName(callback) {
  callback(name);
}

function addTitle(name,callback) {
  var title = "writer";
  callback(name,title);
}

function addGender(name,title,callback) {
  var gender = "male";
  console.log({name,title,gender});
}

printResult();
```

Comment: you wan to print the contents of addGender -> `{name,title,gender}`?

Comment: Yep, right you are @naga - elixir - jar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does `addGender` have a `callback` if you're not using it in the function?

**This works without changing any of the listed functions.**

```js
const name = "sam"

function getName(callback) {
  callback(name);
}

function addTitle(name,callback) {
  var title = "writer";
  callback(name,title);
}

function addGender(name,title,callback) {
  var gender = "male";
  console.log({name,title,gender});
}

function printResult() {
  getName(function(name) {
    addTitle(name, function(name, title) {
      addGender(name, title)
    })
  })
}

printResult();
```

**Here is a modified version where `addGender` uses a `callback`**

```js
const name = "sam"

function getName(callback) {
  callback(name);
}

function addTitle(name,callback) {
  var title = "writer";
  callback(name,title);
}

function addGender(name,title,callback) {
  var gender = "male";
  callback({name,title,gender})
}

function printResult() {
  getName(function(name) {
    addTitle(name, function(name, title) {
      addGender(name, title, function(result) {
        console.log(result)
      })
    })
  })
}

printResult();
```

Comment: Perfect @Neil!! I really appreciate your solution.

Comment: No problem @MITHU, glad I could help. Just curious, which solution out of the two was the one you were after?

Comment: To be honest - either of them is ideal. Thanks.

Comment: I'ill be very glad, if you check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597383/unable-to-fetch-results-using-callback) in order to offer any solution @Neil.